# Regex to disallow consecutive words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my web application user can select questions from a list box and once they select and add a question, i am adding a placeholder in a text-area.

I am adding placeholder in following way

```
[[QuestionCode]]
```

Question code can be Que001, que002...

So how i can disallow user to add two consecutive questions. after selecting quest users need to select an operator then only he can select another question.
For adding operators users can select operator from list-box
They will be added to text-area in following way

```
[[OperatorCode]]
```

So basically user can not add to consecutive question or operators.

**Valid**

```
 [[QuestionCode]][[OperatorCode]][[QuestionCode]]
 [[QuestionCode]][[OperatorCode]] dfbndsbfhb
```

**Invalid**

```
    [[QuestionCode]][[QuestionCode]]
    [[QuestionCode]][[QuestionCode]]sdfdsf
    [[OperatorCode]][[OperatorCode]]
    [[OperatorCode]][[OperatorCode]] dfbndsbfhb
```

How i can achieve it by using Java Script Regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a better example as to what 2 consecutive questions would look like as text? and an example of what is considered valid? i can only extrapolate from your question and I am not particularly sure either.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\[\[[^\]\[]*\]\])(?!\1).*$
```

You can use `backreference` with `lookahead` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/36